# positional argument error when using thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I am new to python and i have written a sample program on threading. The program just opens and reads a file. In the program i have introduced thread that will log the instance like when a file is opened, the thread will write in another file that the file has been opened. When executing the program, i am getting error as function takes 1 positional argument but 19 was given. the program is as below

```
import threading

def writefile(stext):
    f1.write(stext)

if __name = "__main__":
   f1.open("sample1.txt",w)
   f2.open("newfile.txt",r)
   t1 = threading.Thread(target=writefile,args=(new file opened"),)
   t1.start()
   print(f2.read())
   t1.join()
   print("done")
```

When the program is getting executed, i get error as mentioned above. please guide

Regards,
Saumik Vora

Comment: What is `f1` and `f2`?

Comment: Your posted code has many problems, such as `__name` and spurious quotes. It won't even compile as shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=writefile,args=(new file opened"),)
```

should be changed to `t1 = threading.Thread(target=writefile,args=('new file opened",f1))`
Also you need to send the file pointer to the thread target `def writefile(stext,f1):`